# Google Cloud GPU NVENC + Windows 2016

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, windows-server-2016, nvenc

Having tested some GPU+NVENC x.264 encoding successfully on AWS I am now testing with Google Cloud Compute (Tesla P100 GPU running Windows Svr 2016)

It doesn't looks like NVENC is working, has anyone achieved this with windows? or have any pointers?

[GPU Status on Google Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My8ut.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the P100 instances working on unbuntu GCP VMs.  I finally tried updating the driver to the 390 series and it worked(!!)

For ubuntu, the process to update the driver is

`sudo apt-get -y purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-390`

Perhaps this is the issue in the windows VMs too.

(I did not have this problem with the K80 VMs)